# PowerShell WebRequest POST

Tags: powershell

In Windows PowerShell 3.0 was introduced [Invoke-RestMethod](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx) cmdlet.

[Invoke-RestMethod](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx) cmdlet accepts `-Body<Object>` parameter for setting the body of the request.

Due to a certain limitations [Invoke-RestMethod](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx) cmdlet could not be used in our case. From the other hand, an alternative solution described in article [InvokeRestMethod for the Rest of Us](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/10/21/invokerestmethod-for-the-rest-of-us.aspx) suits our needs:

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$request.Method="Get"
$response = $request.GetResponse()
$requestStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
$readStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $requestStream
$data=$readStream.ReadToEnd()
if($response.ContentType -match "application/xml") {
    $results = [xml]$data
} elseif($response.ContentType -match "application/json") {
    $results = $data | ConvertFrom-Json
} else {
    try {
        $results = [xml]$data
    } catch {
        $results = $data | ConvertFrom-Json
    }
}
$results
```

But it is intended for a GET method only.
Could you please suggest how to extend this code sample with the ability to send the body of the request using `POST` method (similar to `Body` parameter in `Invoke-RestMethod`)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, change the line that updates the HTTP method.

```
$request.Method= 'POST';
```

Next, you need to add the message body to the `HttpWebRequest` object. To do that, you need to grab a reference to the request stream, and then add data to it.

```
$Body = [byte[]][char[]]'asdf';
$Request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::CreateHttp('http://www.mywebservicethatiwanttoquery.com/');
$Request.Method = 'POST';
$Stream = $Request.GetRequestStream();
$Stream.Write($Body, 0, $Body.Length);
$Request.GetResponse();
```

**NOTE**: [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/) edition is now open source on GitHub, and cross-platform on Linux, Mac, and Windows. Any issues with the `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet should be reported on the GitHub issue tracker for this project, so they can be tracked and fixed.

Comment: thank you, Trevor! This is the way how i thought it should be implemented but was not sure that this is the best way

Comment: @TrevorSullivan How the body would look like if i have a json on it?

Comment: @campinho: Simply replace the "asdf" with your JSON. :)

Comment: @TrevorSullivan can I send a file this way? Like `$Body = [reports[]]$filecontent;` I got a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144921/how-to-pass-an-array-via-web-request) and now I come over this answer. How do you think, this solution will work in my case?

Comment: @gofr1 did you figure out how to send a file?

Comment: @irl_irl Yeah, I got the answer to this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144921/how-to-pass-an-array-via-web-request)

Comment: One irk with `Invoke-RestMethod` (at least in PS5) was that it throws an exception on 4** error codes making access to the response body a pain.

Answer (score 5):

```
$myID = 666;
#the xml body should begin on column 1 no indentation.
$reqBody = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:MyRequest
    xmlns:ns1="urn:com:foo:bar:v1"
    xmlns:ns2="urn:com:foo:xyz:v1"
    <ns2:MyID>$myID</ns2:MyID>
</ns13:MyRequest>
"@

Write-Host $reqBody;

try
{
    $endPoint = "http://myhost:80/myUri"
    Write-Host ("Querying "+$endPoint)
    $wr = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($endPoint)
    $wr.Method= 'POST';
    $wr.ContentType="application/xml";
    $Body = [byte[]][char[]]$reqBody;
    $wr.Timeout = 10000;

    $Stream = $wr.GetRequestStream();

    $Stream.Write($Body, 0, $Body.Length);

    $Stream.Flush();
    $Stream.Close();

    $resp = $wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()

    $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($resp) 

    $respTxt = $sr.ReadToEnd()

    [System.Xml.XmlDocument] $result = $respTxt
    [String] $rs = $result.DocumentElement.OuterXml
    Write-Host "$($rs)";
}
catch
{
    $errorStatus = "Exception Message: " + $_.Exception.Message;
    Write-Host $errorStatus;
}
```